# Qt Creator Mac OS X git

Tags: git, macos, qt, qt-creator

I recently started working on a c++ application that I was hoping to make cross-platform. I had heard of Qt and decided to give it a try. I have noticed that the documentation for Qt Creator is not very supportive for Mac users. I am having trouble finding documentation on how to setup my username and password for git so I can push to my github repo. I have found that ssh-askpass is not installed on Mac and was hoping to setup my login info so I didn't have to worry about using the askpass. Any help on how to setup up my login info in Qt Creator is much appreciated.

Comment: If it doesn't work well then don't use QtCreator for your git interaction; use SourceTree instead and keep development and source control separate.

Comment: I'll stick to the command line for git then. Was just hoping someone knew how to configure git for the mac